# Retrofit beta 2 - Could not find class 'com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient'

Tags: android, retrofit

I was wondering if someone could assist me. I recently upgraded my Android application to use Retrofit 2.0 beta and then fixed my code accordingly. I'm using Eclipse.

When I go to make calls out, I get the following error:

```
Could not find class 'com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient', referenced from method retrofit.Retrofit$Builder.build
```

Followed by a lot of other issues such as:

```
12-16 23:24:36.233: I/dalvikvm(2369): Could not find method com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.source, referenced from method retrofit.Utils.readBodyToBytesIfNecessary

12-16 23:24:36.233: W/dalvikvm(2369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10823: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/ResponseBody;.source ()Lokio/BufferedSource;
```

I did some googling and found a variety of answers (one by Jake Wharton himself) but quite frankly all of it is over my head about the proper way to handle this. I need to go and manually patch this myself or something? I really don't get it..

Any chance someone could illuminate this for me to some extent?

Thanks so much!

Comment: show us your gradle file

Comment: I'm not using gradle

Comment: Have you tried add dependency like ```<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```  in your build config.

Comment: I'm not using anything that would have a build.config I think (i'm just using eclipse with 2 jar files added as libraries)

Comment: @user3379785 OK, check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since retrofit 2.0, OKHttp become mandatory dependency.

Based on the [changelog here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

### Version 2.0.0-beta1 *(2015-08-27)*

- New: OkHttp is now required as a dependency. Types like `TypedInput` and `TypedOutput` (and its
  implementations), `Request`, and `Header` have been replaced with OkHttp types like `RequestBody`,
  `ResponseBody`, and `Headers`.

You can download the OKHttp jar from [here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: Thanks - I had to also add okio and then it worked. I really appreciate all of you taking the time out to help me.